# How to add plugin (ibm content navigator) to intellij idea

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, ibm-content-navigator

How to add plugin **ibm content navigator** to intellij idea, to use as in eclipse?

In eclipse i added  `com.ibm.ecm.icn.facet.EDSPlugin.2.0.2.jar` and `com.ibm.ecm.icn.plugin.202` to dir `eclipse\dropins`, plugin seems like this:

[image: eclipse plugin]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. The two use different plug-in mechanisms. This is like trying to run a Linux binary on macOS.

Comment: otherwise, just use eclipse for the scaffolding of the project with the plugin and continue the develoment on intellij. For the newer versions of eclipse you will need to rebuild the plugin. The source can be found here: https://github.com/ibm-ecm/ibm-content-navigator-samples/tree/master/eclipsePlugin